# MapControl displays Yandex Maps tiles with offset

Tags: c#, maps, windows-phone-8.1, yandex-maps

I'm developing **Windows Phone 8.1** application and I want to display `Yandex Maps` instead of `Bing Maps` in MapControl. I've set a new tile datasource with yandex url. It works, but tiles are displayed with a small vertical offset.

The offset only is not a problem, but it affects on placemarks - they are displayed in wrong position on yandex tiles, but correct in bing tiles.

The problem is not in coordinates because I pick them from original yandex maps in browser.

In example below, colored tiles are provided by yandex and gray shape is from bing maps.

[image: Tile offset example]

**Setting yandex tiles in MapControl:**

```
HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource("http://vec02.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x={x}&y={y}&z={zoomlevel}");
MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);
MyMapControl.TileSources.Add(tileSource);
```

I've tried to intercept MapControl's tile request and decrement the value of `y` coordinate but the result was completely wrong.

**Result of intercepting request and modifying value of `y`**

[image]

[MSDN: MapControl tile overlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632728.aspx#customUri)

Comment: Yandex has different projection than google and bing. 
visit [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69287/openlayers-with-yandex-layer-position-issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Yandex Maps and Bing Maps have slightly different map projections. I am not an expert on projections however, you can see the difference in [MercatorProjection](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET.Projections/MercatorProjection.cs) (implemented for Bing Map) and [MercatorProjectionYandex](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.Core/GMap.NET.Projections/MercatorProjectionYandex.cs) (implemented for Yandex Maps) classes implemented for [Great Maps for Windows Forms & Presentation](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static Point WGS84ToBing(Point coordinate)
    {
        double d = coordinate.X * Math.PI / 180, m = coordinate.Y * Math.PI / 180, l = 6378137, k = 0.0818191908426, f = k * Math.Sin(m);
        double h = Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + m / 2), j = Math.Pow(Math.Tan(Math.PI / 4 + Math.Asin(f) / 2), k), i = h / j;

        return new Point(l * d, l * Math.Log(i));
    }

    public static Point BingtoWGS84Mercator(Point point)
    {
        double lon = (point.X / 20037508.34) * 180;
        double lat = (point.Y / 20037508.34) * 180;

        lat = 180 / Math.PI * (2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(lat * Math.PI / 180)) - Math.PI / 2);

        return new Point(lon, lat);
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
    HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource("http://vec02.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&v=2.2.3&x={x}&y={y}&z={zoomlevel}");

    MapTileSource tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource)
    {
        Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement
    };

    map.Style = MapStyle.None;
    map.TileSources.Add(tileSource);

    Point bingPoint = WGS84ToBing(new Point(47.245252, 56.139498));
    Point yandexCoordinates = BingtoWGS84Mercator(new Point(bingPoint.X, bingPoint.Y));

    map.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Longitude = yandexCoordinates.X, Latitude = yandexCoordinates.Y });
```